# Attempting Multiple Browser - Speech to Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to implement an offline speech recognition run in the browser. I want this to run in ALL browsers (Safari included). However, I am having trouble implementing this. I've looked at Pocketsphinx.js (https://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/), but this would only work in at best Chrome and Firefox. How would I implement this in all browsers (including Safari -- like IBM and Google Speech Cloud do -- withOUT using a costly api that requires internet). I was thinking about saving the user's voice to a .wav file and then sending it to be processed, but I do not know if this would too inefficient. (I'm coding a nodejs/express app).

Please help!

FYI: I know there are APIs out there (Web Speech API -- only works on Chrome) (IBM, Google Speech (but these require internet access and aren't free)).